# How to merge two objects and calculate the average of their values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning TDD and I would like to create a function to expected this result.

```
//What I expect

[
    {book_id: 1, name:'NameBook', average: x},
    {book_id: 2, name:'NameBook', average: x},
    {book_id: 3, name:'NameBook', average: x},
    {book_id: 4, name:'NameBook', average: x},
    {book_id: 5, name:'NameBook', average: x},
    {book_id: 6, name:'NameBook', average: x},
    {book_id: 7, name:'NameBook', average: x},
]
```

I got to merge two objects with the filter function but I'm having difficulties calculating the average and sum of these values where the id's are equal.

I'm posting here what I got to do https://jsfiddle.net/thiagolmoraes/5xsk7Lgw/1/

Anyone can help me.

```js
    const getBooks = () => {
        return [
            { id: 1, name: 'Python Data Science' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Python Machine Learning' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Development Flask' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Mongo Database' },
            { id: 5, name: 'ULM for Dummies' },
            { id: 6, name: 'Java for Dummies' },
            { id: 7, name: 'Learn Rust in 2 hours' },
        ]
    }


 const getRating = () => {
        return [
            { book_id: 1, client_id: 1, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 1, client_id: 4, rating: 5 },
            { book_id: 1, client_id: 25, rating: 5 },
            { book_id: 1, client_id: 2112, rating: 4 },
    
            { book_id: 2, client_id: 34, rating: 3 },
            { book_id: 2, client_id: 123, rating: 4 },
            { book_id: 2, client_id: 23, rating: 4 },
            { book_id: 2, client_id: 255, rating: 4 },
    
            { book_id: 3, client_id: 98, rating: 2 },
            { book_id: 3, client_id: 45, rating: 1 },
            { book_id: 3, client_id: 223, rating: 3 },
            { book_id: 3, client_id: 213, rating: 1.5 },
    
            { book_id: 4, client_id: 652, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 4, client_id: 42, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 4, client_id: 562, rating: 4.5 },
    
            { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
            { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
            { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
    
            { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    
            { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
            { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        ]
    }
    

const getBooksWithRatings = () => {
    return getBooks().map((book) => {
        book.ratings = getRating().filter((r) => r.book_id === book.id);
        return book;
    });

};
    
console.log(getBooksWithRatings())
```

Comment: Seems like you made a good attempt over in the JS Fiddle! Would you mind copying it over into your question here so it's easier for people to see?

Comment: Sorry, I will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you were almost there. You just need to calculate the sum of the ratings array and then divide by its length. This should complete the task for you.

```js
const getBooks = () => {
  return [
    { id: 1, name: "Python Data Science" },
    { id: 2, name: "Python Machine Learning" },
    { id: 3, name: "Development Flask" },
    { id: 4, name: "Mongo Database" },
    { id: 5, name: "ULM for Dummies" },
    { id: 6, name: "Java for Dummies" },
    { id: 7, name: "Learn Rust in 2 hours" },
  ];
};

const getRating = () => {
  return [
    { book_id: 1, client_id: 1, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 1, client_id: 4, rating: 5 },
    { book_id: 1, client_id: 25, rating: 5 },
    { book_id: 1, client_id: 2112, rating: 4 },

    { book_id: 2, client_id: 34, rating: 3 },
    { book_id: 2, client_id: 123, rating: 4 },
    { book_id: 2, client_id: 23, rating: 4 },
    { book_id: 2, client_id: 255, rating: 4 },

    { book_id: 3, client_id: 98, rating: 2 },
    { book_id: 3, client_id: 45, rating: 1 },
    { book_id: 3, client_id: 223, rating: 3 },
    { book_id: 3, client_id: 213, rating: 1.5 },

    { book_id: 4, client_id: 652, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 4, client_id: 42, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 4, client_id: 562, rating: 4.5 },

    { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
    { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
    { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },

    { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },

    { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
  ];
};

const getBooksWithRatings = () => {
  return getBooks().map((book) => {
    const ratings = getRating().filter((r) => r.book_id === book.id);
    book.average = ratings.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.rating, 0) / ratings.length;
    return book;
  });
};

console.log(getBooksWithRatings());
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, Could you explain me about this reduce?

Comment: Sure, the `reduce` method takes a function with up to four arguments: the accumulator, the current element, the index of the current element, and the original array. I'm only using the first two arguments here. The `0` is the initial value for our accumulator. `reduce` iterates through the array and adds `e.rating` to the accumulator, coming up with a new accumulator each time. Essentially, this sums `el.rating` over the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce` to find the sum of the filtered array and divide by its length to find the average. To prevent modifying the objects in the original array, you can use spread syntax.

```js
const getBooks = () => {
    return [
        { id: 1, name: 'Python Data Science' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Python Machine Learning' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Development Flask' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Mongo Database' },
        { id: 5, name: 'ULM for Dummies' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Java for Dummies' },
        { id: 7, name: 'Learn Rust in 2 hours' },
    ]
}

const getRating = () => {
    return [
        { book_id: 1, client_id: 1, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 1, client_id: 4, rating: 5 },
        { book_id: 1, client_id: 25, rating: 5 },
        { book_id: 1, client_id: 2112, rating: 4 },

        { book_id: 2, client_id: 34, rating: 3 },
        { book_id: 2, client_id: 123, rating: 4 },
        { book_id: 2, client_id: 23, rating: 4 },
        { book_id: 2, client_id: 255, rating: 4 },

        { book_id: 3, client_id: 98, rating: 2 },
        { book_id: 3, client_id: 45, rating: 1 },
        { book_id: 3, client_id: 223, rating: 3 },
        { book_id: 3, client_id: 213, rating: 1.5 },

        { book_id: 4, client_id: 652, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 4, client_id: 42, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 4, client_id: 562, rating: 4.5 },

        { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
        { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },
        { book_id: 5, client_id: 2, rating: 5 },

        { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 6, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },

        { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
        { book_id: 7, client_id: 2, rating: 4.5 },
    ]
}


const getBooksWithRatings = () => {
    return getBooks().map(book => {
        const ratings = getRating().filter((r) => r.book_id === book.id);
        return {...book, average: ratings.reduce((acc,{rating})=>acc+rating, 0) / ratings.length};
    });

};

console.log(getBooksWithRatings())
```